# A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, opencsv

I am using EPPlus to read .csv file in vb.net.
When I run this code, I get the error "A disk error occurred during a write operation.

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))"

Here is my code :

```
Public Function ImportExcelSheet(ByVal filePath As String) As DataTable
    Dim dtImportData As New DataTable()
    Try
        'If csv file have header then "true" else "false"
        Dim hasHeader As Boolean = True
        Using pck = New OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage()
            Using stream = File.OpenRead(filePath)
                pck.Load(stream)
            End Using
```

What should I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 7):

I had the same error with a plugin I had created to import from excel. Originally I had saved the import file as .xls.

I opened this excel spreadsheet and **resaved as .xlsx.**

This solved the problem.

So maybe it is the file format that the csv was saved as.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error reading xls file. It turns out the workbook had hidden rows on the first sheet. I inspected the document and removed the hidden rows and it worked perfectly