# Import a CSV or XLSX Into A DataTable Using EPPLus

Tags: c#, datatable, epplus, epplus-4

I found a thread on SO and am attempting to import a csv or xls or xlsx into a C# DataTable - but I am getting the below stack trace error:

```
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
  HResult=0x8003001D
  Message=A disk error occurred during a write operation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8003001D (STG_E_WRITEFAULT))
  Source=EPPlus
```

This is the code that I am trying to use to import the file - what do I need to change so this executes as it should?

```
        private OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    public static DataTable GetDataTableFromExcel(string path, bool hasHeader = true)
    {
        using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
        {
            using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
            {
                pck.Load(stream);
            }
            var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
            foreach (var firstRowCell in ws.Cells[1, 1, 1, ws.Dimension.End.Column])
            {
                tbl.Columns.Add(hasHeader ? firstRowCell.Text : string.Format("Column {0}", firstRowCell.Start.Column));
            }
            var startRow = hasHeader ? 2 : 1;
            for (int rowNum = startRow; rowNum <= ws.Dimension.End.Row; rowNum++)
            {
                var wsRow = ws.Cells[rowNum, 1, rowNum, ws.Dimension.End.Column];
                DataRow row = tbl.Rows.Add();
                foreach (var cell in wsRow)
                {
                    row[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                }
            }
            return tbl;
        }
    }

    private void btnImportSpreadsheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable spreadsheetImport = new DataTable();
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.csv;";
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            spreadsheetImport = GetDataTableFromExcel(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861419/a-disk-error-occurred-during-a-write-operation-exception-from-hresult-0x80030

Comment: @Magnetron - the line of code that throws the error is - pck.Load(stream)

Comment: This error only occurs reading csv? Because epplus doesn't support csv, only xlsx

Comment: @Magnetron - wait so EPPlus can write to a csv but can not read it back in?

Comment: Actually it can read, but using LoadFromText: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40360112/csv-with-epplus-parsing-issues

Comment: My values do not have decimals, should I still use LoadFromText to import a csv and the above method for a .xl*

Comment: Yes, just don't use the `DataTypes` property

Comment: @user2676140 this worked for you? mind if I post as an answer? Also note that EPPlus doesn't work with xls

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330799/5836671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For work with csv, you must use `LoadFromText`. Also note that EPPlus can not work with xls, it can read xlsx and xlsm and write xlsx.

```
char csvDelimiter = ';';
using(var pck = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = null;
    if(path.EndsWith(".csv"))
    {
        ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        ExcelTextFormat format = new ExcelTextFormat()
        {
            Delimiter = csvDelimiter 
        };
        ws.Cells[1, 1].LoadFromText(File.ReadAllText(path), format);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(path))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    }

    //The rest of your code

}
```

Another option is to use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader), as it can read xls, xlsx and csv, but cannot write. It has an [extension that converts a file to a `DataSet`](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader#asdataset-configuration-options)

Comment: one thing to note to future views is that the variable csvDelimter should be set to whatever your delimter in the csv is.  In my instance the delimiter was a ',' not a ';' - :)